# Using powershell to read a txt file with multiple values then using those values to copy files from server

Tags: powershell-3.0

So very new to powershell, trying to automate some exe installs.. Want to create a txt file that developers can include a value that my powershell script will use to pull data from a server and copy data to local machine for install. 
For example
Developer puts package name mop1300x, aba1100s and rrr2234 in a text file the ps script will read those go to server \ABC copy those folders to the local machine. Any help would be awesome

Was thinking about 
Copy-item "\ABC\" -container -recuse \$server\c$\windows\temp

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach($program in get-content "C:\path\to\.txt"){
    copy-item -Path \\server\c$\path\to\exes\$program -Destination C:\temp -recurse
}
```

This will read your text file, and for each name in it (mop1300x, aba1100s etc.) it will copy that file/folder to C:\temp\ on your local machine. Given that this script is run from the local machine and that your text file has each name of program on seperate line like:

```
mop1300x
aba1100s
rrr2234
```

and that all the programs are in the same folder on the server